# How do I find my jsperf tests?

Tags: search, account, jsperf

Now for the noob question of the week. How do I find my jsPerf tests? There's no "account" as far as I can find out, and looking for my name or url doesn't appear to help!

I'd also like to search by name, website, etc., and "personal" search queries of others I know.

-- Owen

Comment: Did you enter your name before you ran your test? When I search "jsperf My Name" I see my jsperf tests, and when I search "jsperf NameOfTest" I also see the specific test

Comment: That seems to work via google.  Odd that the jsperf site doesn't have a search of its own.  A "site search" (owen densmore site:jsperf.com) works fine too.

Comment: @backspaces...yes, a Google search is what I meant. Sorry, I thought you meant searching in general :)

Comment: Actually, that's where you nailed it: I was thinking too narrowly, thinking jsperf's search would work well, just putting in my name.  Nope, came up empty.  But your approach of a wider search, and the addition of a site:jsperf.com did the trick.  Feel free to post an answer of these and I'll accept it.  Otherwise I'll do so later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since jsperf does not currently have user accounts, the easiest way to search is via search engine.

- Search by "jsperf" + your_name (as entered on jsperf) to find all tests you've run under that name
- Search by "jsperf" + title_of_test to find a specific test you have run
- Go to this GitHub url https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jsperf.com to find more info on the files used to create jsperf, the license, and other tips